# Can we re-run the Job Workflow starting from where it failed in AWX?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Say I have a Job workflow in AWX consisting of several job templates. Say due to some reason one of the job template failed and the flow stops on failure. 
I corrected my coding mistake. 
Now is there a way to re-run the same workflow but this time not by start but starting from where it failed till the last Job template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For job workflow re-launch doesn't apply. See below quoted from Ansible docs.

The relaunch operation only applies to relaunches of playbook runs and does not apply to a system job, project/inventory updates, system jobs, workflow jobs, etc.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.3.1/html/userguide/jobs.html